# Como fazer requisições via c#? WebRequest vs HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, http, segurança, webrequest

Tenho um projeto em .Net Framework 4.6.1, e em minhas pesquisas concluí que posso usar a classe [WebRequest](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class) para fazer requisições a outros servições web via backend.

1. Eu gostaria de poder realizar requisições utilizando qualquer [verbo HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods).
2. Também poder fazer uso do [protocolo SSL/TLS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) quando necessário.

---

1. A classe WebRequest é a única disponível para esse fim?
2. Além dos requisitos acima, considerando performance e segurança, essa é a forma mais indicada para estabelecer conexões através da plataforma .net?

### Edição:

Considere os seguintes trechos de código:

**Caso 1:**

```
public class MyServiceController : ApiController
{
    public void Post()
    {
        // ...
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var result = httpClient.GetAsync("https://pt.stackoverflow.com");
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Caso 2:**

```
public class MyServiceController : ApiController
{
    public void Post()
    {
        // ...

        var request = WebRequest.Create("https://pt.stackoverflow.com");
        request.Method = "GET";
        // ...

        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

> **1.** Se ambos podem me auxiliar a fazer uma requisição em C#, qual seria a
> diferença entre eles? Quais os cenários mais indicados?
>
> **2.** Ambos possuem suporte para qualquer verbo HTTP?
>
> **3.** Ambos possuem suporte para o uso do protocolo SSL/TLS?
>
> **4.** Qual é mais performático?
>
> **5.** Algum deles está obsoleto e pode me oferecer riscos de segurança na requisição?

Comment: Dê uma olhadinha na classe `HttpClient` e veja se te atende

Comment: @KevinKouketsu muito obrigado pelo comentário. Se puder postar uma resposta com um breve comparativo entre WebRequest e HttpClient acredito que já possa aceitá-la.

Answer (score 1):

O HttpClient é a classe mais atual para ser utilizada (a partir do 4.5), inclusive no ASP.NET Core (Qual eu uso) é possível aplicar comportamentos de resiliência em micro-serviços usando o [Polly](http://www.thepollyproject.org/)

1. Essa classe permite o uso de chamadas para vários servidores e hosts na mesma instancia e a quantidade que quiser.
2. Você pode derivá-la para sua próprias classes especializadas.
3. Foi escrita usando o TAP ([Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap)) podendo lidar com solicitações assíncronas, uso do Await, gerenciar solicitações pendentes etc...
4. Abstraiu muito coisa, sendo muito mais fácil a implementação e com menos linhas de código.
5. Suporta ssl

O macoratti fez uma comparação que você pode encontrar clicando [aqui](http://www.macoratti.net/16/08/net_web1.htm)

Espero ter ajudado!